# my fields not reflecting in the databse only for city, course and secon name

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

[database showing other entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg8mp.png)

This is my code in the register view.. for first name, and others except course, city , secondname not showing in the database, at the same time it allows me to login. have tried changing a few things but still no reflection

```
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{    url('/register') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }} first name, 
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="second" class="col-md-4 control-label">Second Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="second" type="text" class="form-control" name="second" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="city" class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control" name="city" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="course" class="col-md-4 control-label">course</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="course" type="text" class="form-control" name="course" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**authcontroller**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
  protected function create(array $data)
     {
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: show your controller code.

Comment: @NikhilVaghla done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to user model. Search for the variable.

```
protected $fillable
```

Add your fields to this array.